# What's The Significance of the House in "Crack in Stoney Port"?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, mods

I just finished "[Crack in Stoney Port](http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/763078-minecraft-adventure-map-crack-in-stoney-port/)", but I don't get why the house is there.  The notes said that I "felt that was the right place" and that "whatever was happening had something to do with this place", but it didn't appear to me to have any significance.

I found the house, dead-ended, then I

> went back to where the torches first started going inland and I followed the underwater glowstone path.

I could've finished it without ever bothering to investigate the torch trail.

What's the point of that house?

Answer (score 1):

There is a stone button on one of the walls. Push it and a piston opens part of the floor, allowing you to continue down.